# Access the variable from for_each in the for_each loop

Tags: c++11, foreach

I have Code that looks like this:

```
int multiplyBy2 (int x) {return x*2;}
int add10 (int x) {return x+10;}
int divideBy2 (int x) {return x/2;}

QVector<int> doAnything(QVector<int> list, QVector<std::function<int (int)>> methods){

    for(int i = 0; i< methods.size(); i++){
        std::transform(list.begin(), list.end() , list.begin() ,methods.at(i));
    }
    return list;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QVector<int> list {1,2,3,4,5};
    QVector<std::function<int (int)>> functions {multiplyBy2 , add10 , divideBy2};

    auto result = doAnything(list, functions);
    std::for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), [](int i){qDebug() << i;});
    return 0;
}
```

The function doAnything performs a list of functions on a list of values.
This code works fine.

Now I have tried, to do this in a for_each loop:

```
std::for_each(methods.begin(), methods.end(),
               std::transform (list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin() , varFromForEach));
```

My problem is that I doesn't know how to access the variable from the for_each loop in the for_each loop like `it` in Kotlin or `_` in scala

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). _The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following: `void fun(const Type &a);` The signature does not need to have `const &`. The type `Type` must be such that an object of type `InputIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type`._ The `a` is in this case the "variable from for_each loop".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You attempt to *call* `std::transform` in your `std::for_each` call.

Instead create a lambda, capturing `list` and taking the value from `std::for_each` (the `std::function` object) as an argument, and call `std::transform` in the lambda:

```
std::for_each(methods.begin(), methods.end(),
              [&list](std::function<int(int)>& f)
              {
                  std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin(), f);
              });
```

---

You can of course use a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) as well:

```
for (auto& f : methods)
{
    std::transform(list.begin(), list.end(), list.begin(), f);
}
```

Comment: `for_each` is kind of redundant anyway. It served a purpose in C++03, but after C++11 I don't think it makes much sense to use it.

Comment: It's not redundant. It serves the purpose of improved readability better than a range-based for loop in many cases. Especially if you are working a lot with STL algorithms anyways.